# P2P synchronization: can a player update fields of other players?

Tags: networking, synchronization, anti-cheat

I know that synchronization is a huge topic, so I have minimized the problem to this example case.

Let's say, Alice and Bob are playing a P2P game, fighting against each other. If Alice hits Bob, how should I do the network component to make Bob's HP decrease?

I can think of two approaches:

1. Alice perform a Bob.HP--, then send Bob's reduced HP to Bob.
2. Alice send a "I just hit Bob" signal to Bob. Bob checks it, and reduce its own HP, then send his new HP to everyone including Alice.

I think the second approach is better because I don't think a player in a P2P game should be able to modify other players' private fields. Otherwise cheating would be too easy, right?

My philosophy is that in a P2P game especially, a player's attributes and all attributes of its belonging objects should only be updated by the player himself. However, I can't prove that this is right. Could someone give me some evidence? Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, without a (trusted, independent) 3rd party, stopping the other party from cheating is impossible.  The design of your game _may_ limit the extent of cheating; however, in any situation where either party can be (and is equally likely to be) hostile, you need somebody they **both** will trust.

Answer (score 3):

It's not good practice to directly alter other players' properties, so I would recommend your second option.

Though I would also recommend adding checks to make sure that peers don't spam "I hit you" messages without actually having hit the player.

Comment: To limit cheating as much as possible without a server, the only messages you should be sending should be player input.  Then both clients simulate the gameplay locally, and come to the same solution.  So if you're making a fighting game, player A says, "I'm starting my kick" and 6 frames later player B thinks, "welp I got hit by the kick now" instead of player A potentially sending "I hit you for 1 billion damage" 20 times every frame.